# Defining a subclass exclusively for a slightly different data structure

Tags: matlab, class, oop, inheritance, subclass

I decided to start using OOP to make my code more modular, but I still have to learn a lot regarding what's best practice.

#### Current data structure

In this particular case I am trying to define a class hierarchy that deals with (on the lowest level) binary oscilloscope data for a variety of sensors. Independent of sensor characteristics, I defined the class `ScopeData` that simply reads the binary files and returns x- and y-data along with some generic characteristics:

```
classdef ScopeData

    properties
        Filename
        xdata
        ydata
    end

    properties (Access = private)
        % Some properties only used to extract data from the binary file
    end

    properties (Access = protected)
        fid = -1 % used in reading data and closing upon destruction

        % Properties that are required to quickly navigate to the data
        % locations in the binary file
    end

    properties (Dependent = true)
        Raw % raw data 
    end

    %% Methods related to constructing/destructing
    methods
        function obj = ScopeData(filepath)

            % Input argument checking is done here

            % Assign the filename
            obj.Filename = filepath;

            % Open the file and read its contents
            obj.Open;
            obj.Read;
        end


        function obj = Open(obj)
            % Opens obj.Filename and extracts all info required to read out
            % the data
        end

        function obj = Read(obj)
            rawdata = obj.Raw; % get the raw data

            % Some minimal processing and averaging to get xdata and ydata
            obj.xdata = SomeFunction(rawdata);
            obj.ydata = SomeOtherFunction(rawdata);

        end
    end

    %% Get/set methods
    methods
        function rawdata = get.Raw(obj)
            % uses the private properties to efficiently extract the raw data
        end
    end

end
```

For each of the different types of sensors I created subclasses `SensorXYZData` that inherit from `ScopeData`. Their additional properties are all exclusive to the particular sensor and are used to further process the data, e.g.:

```
classdef SensorXData < ScopeData

    properties
        % Sensor-specific properties
        SensorLocation
        SensorConfiguration
    end

    properties (Dependent = true)
        % Sensor-specific dependent properties
    end

    methods
        function obj = SensorXData(filepath, SensorLocation, SensorConfiguration)
            % Initialize object
            obj = obj@ScopeData(filepath);

            % Assign sensor-specific properties

            % Do some additional processing

        end
    end

    methods
        % Get/set methods for the dependent properties
    end

end
```

The above data structure allows me to define individual objects for each of my sensors that all read a single binary file. I currently make arrays of objects outside the class files for every family of sensors. Raw data is not stored, but can be requested easily.

#### What I'm trying to do

From the different sensor families, only the *SensorX* family will be dealing with both single data files (default) and multiple data files per sensor (a different type of experiment).
On a per-file basis, the latter will require exactly the same processing as the former, but there will also be additional properties and processing steps exclusive to the multiple-file case.

I am currently trying to implement this special case by having an additional subclass `SensorXArrayData` that inherits from `SensorXData`:

```
classdef SensorXArrayData < SensorXData

    properties
        ExtraProperties
    end

    properties (Dependent = true)
        % Dependent variables specific to this data
    end

    methods
        function obj = SensorXArrayData(MultipleFilepaths, SensorLocation, SensorConfiguration, ExtraProperties)
            % Initialize object - I am only allowed to call obj@SensorXData once, so this currently doesn't work.
            obj = obj@SensorXData(MultipleFilepaths, SensorLocation, SensorConfiguration);

            % Assign the extra properties

            % More processing that is specific

        end
    end

    methods
        % Get/set methods for the dependent variables
    end

end
```

In order to get the above to work, some additional steps will need to be taken and I'm trying to figure out the most appropriate way.

One of the options seems to be to make the `ScopeData` superclass compatible with multiple-file inputs and work from there. Is there also a way where I can leave `ScopeData` and `SensorXData` untouched?

Comment: All of these questions are subjective and highly dependent on your actual application, which you haven't detailed. Even if you had, it's still a totally subjective assessment. If this is what you need to do to get the necessary functionality, then do it. It doesn't *not* make sense. I'm not really sure what you're expecting to hear.

Comment: @excaza what additional details do you expect to make this more specific? I am mostly curious how I can solve my "desired subclass" issue with the different style of data. Finding out that it is (not) possible in the way I'm currently trying to build my tools should also automatically answer whether my current implementation makes sense.

Comment: *What* desired subclass issue? All we have is "However, I'm having trouble getting the constructor to work". Please see: [mcve]. You have an (unclear) objective question buried inside a bunch of subjective ones. If your implementation achieves the desired behavior, then it makes sense. I'm not really sure how you expect others to judge it for you, or what criteria you'd like us to use to even make such a judgement.

Comment: If you want to treat `SensorXArrayData` as a single object, you should only be calling the superclass constructors once anyway. It sounds like you should just reimplement the methods to treat your *properties* as arrays instead of scalars (i.e. instead of having a property that stores a single data file string, have that property store a cell array of data file strings). You might not need a new class at all; just generalize the constructor/methods of `SensorXData` to handle arrays of data files.

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the pointers. I have updated my post. Hopefully this is more clear.

Comment: @gnovice - That seems to be one of the possible approaches indeed. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without touching SensorXData and/or ScopeData.

Comment: How about creating a new class that holds a set of `SensorXData` objects and has whatever methods you need to work on all their data jointly?  You don't need to inherit, if the inherited class doesn't really match with your base class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is "implementing an interface" in your class (Java terminology). The way it works in MATLAB is using [multiple inheritance](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/subclassing-multiple-classes.html), which looks like this:

```
classdef ClassName < SuperClass1 & SuperClass2
```

I believe that the consensus in OOP in recent years is the so-called "[composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)", which basically means that you should focus on what your class *does* and not on what your class *is*.

#### How to apply this to your problem?

Add several classes that look like this:

```
classdef (Abstract) SomeFeatureInterface < handle
% This is a specialized interface for doing operation XYZ.
  properties (Abstract = true, Access = protected, Constant = true)
    SOME_CONSTANT;
  end  

  methods (Abstract = true, Access = public) % This doesn't have to be abstract, you can add a
    outName = methodName(obj)                % default implementation if relevant.
  end
  
end
```

Then your derived classes' declarations will look like shopping lists, that is, you add whichever functionality is needed right from the class declaration by inheriting from the relevant interface (abstract) classes:

```
classdef SensorXData < ScopeData & SingleFileInterface & MultiFileInterface

classdef SensorYData < ScopeData & SingleFileInterface
```

This way, `SensorXData` will contain the relevant function for handling multiple-files, while `SensorYData` will not. Furthermore, this will ensure a shallow inheritance, which is considered good.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a good way to go. Does it make sense to turn the interfaces really into layers in between a generic data reading class and the specific sensor classes? i.e. _SingleFileInterface_ and _MultiFileInterface_ inherit from a rewritten _ScopeData_ class and the _SensorXYZData_ classes then inherit from _SingleFileInterface_ and/or _MultiFileInterface_ (and no longer from _ScopeData_).

Comment: That is considered a bad idea, see: "[deadly diamond of death](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)". These interfaces act as "[mix-ins](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)" and are typically top-level classes.

Comment: If, for some reason, you do decide that a diamond is the only way to go, there is some discussion on how to avoid its deadliness [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/93189-how-does-matlab-solve-the-diamond-problem-in-multiple-inheritance).

Comment: Good to know. I've marked your answer as accepted. This will be the approach I'm going to try to pursue. Thanks!